# Ears of corn in grams

Tags: baking, measurements, corn, conversion

I found an interesting recipe (http://www.icouldkillfordessert.com.br/receitas/mingau-de-milho/) for corn porridge, in it was necessary "3 ears of corn" for the amount of porridge.

Suppose I don't find the corn on the cob and can only buy it in a can, how many grams of corn does the proportion of the recipe ordered?

Recipe:

- 3 ears of corn;
- 500ml of milk;
- 1/2 cup of sugar;
- 1 pinch of salt;
- Cinnamon.

Comment: Your question is interesting as such, but on a side note, the recipe will not work with corn from the can. You need raw corn.

Answer (score 8):

I agree with @rumtscho that you are unlikely to get the desired results from canned corn as you really probably need raw.  If you do try canned, make sure it is whole kernel type and that might improve your results.  If you cannot get fresh corn, frozen, uncooked corn might work, but even that is usually blanched which might be enough to change the results too much for your desired results, and I would again try for whole kernel, not cut.

Digging around a bit, I found a blog claim that a medium ear of corn yields an average of 3/4 cup of kernels.  Ears of corn vary substantially in size, for a recipe that gives a measure in ears, not in volume or weight, I would immediately say that exact amount is not critical, you just need a very rough amount so I would use the 3/4 cup as being roughly correct.  If weight works better for you, a cup of corn kernels should be about 4.5 ounces or 125 grams (from another blog http://www.veg-world.com/articles/cups.htm), so your three ears would be ballpark of maybe 275 grams with an assumption that exact measurement is not critical.

ETA from @Jolenealalaska, adding a part as creamed corn may very well get you some of the missing goodness in both canned and frozen corn.  I might even try a higher cream corn ratio than their 3-to-1 suggestion.  A bit of experimentation may get you close to your target.

Comment: I would recommend 3 parts whole kernel to 1 part cream-style if it's available. It still might not work, but the cream-style will add that milkiness that comes from scraping the cobs.

Comment: Perhaps a better "plan b" would be to use finely milled polenta?

Comment: @Jolenealaska yes, agree, the cream-style may push it in the right direction combined with whole kernel.  Good call.

Comment: I'm pretty sure I've had this before, and it was definitely a bit different from what you'd get from frozen/creamed corn - probably still worth making, but I wouldn't judge the recipe on it.

Comment: To summarize: so that's 93,75 g per ear (medium)